# TFS Team Project Collection do not work with assemblies of version 15, only with 12

Tags: .net, tfs, nuget, version, tfs-sdk

I have my little app to play with TFS. I get all the required assemblies by NuGet (version `15.112.1`).

But with this version my application do not work. I do not get any exception, but the `GetService<T>()` on the `TfsTeamProjectCollection` always returns null.

If I forgot about NuGet and I will add the required assemblies by the `'Add Reference'` option, then everything works fine. But those assemblies are then of the version `12.0.21005.1`.

My application is targeting `.NET Framework 4.6.2`, I am using `Visual Studio 2017`. The TFS server to which I am connecting is the latest, version `15.112.26307.0`.

Any ideas why newest version does not work, only the old one?

Required assemblies:

- `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client`
- `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common`
- `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client`
- `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common`

**Edit, 15/06/2017:**

As aksed, I am sharing the code which I am using:

```
var teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://myTfsServer/DefaultCollection/"));
var workItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

Comment: Read this, then update your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Could you please share your code which include the GetService<T>()  here for further troubleshoot ?

Answer (score 0):

The new version works fine. Refer to these steps:

1. Create a new project (e.g. console application)
2. Install [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/), then it will add necessary assemblies automatically.
3. Coding